# Как создать ссылку на определённое место страницы html

Tags: html, html5

Необходимо, что бы при нажатии страница скроллилась вниз до нужного места, набросал такой код:

```html
<ul>
    <li> <a href="#search-subdomains"> Search Subdomain </a></li>
</ul>
```

И на экран вниз:

```html
<div class="container" href = "#">
    <h1 id="#search-subdomains">Search subdomains.</h1>
</div>
```

При нажатии на кнопку он не скроллит, что делать?

Comment: id="#search-subdomains" - решетка лишняя

Comment: Спасибо тебе, друг!

Answer (score 0):

Понимаю что решение задачи есть, но для эксперимента можете попробовать ещё такой код:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <!-- Якорная Ссылка -->
      <a href="#search-subdomains"> Search Subdomain </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <div class="container" href="#">
    <a name="search-subdomains">
      <h1>Search subdomains.</h1>
    </a>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: У автора данного вопроса была опечатка в коде, из-за чего никакого скроллинга не было.

Comment: Я уже понял, просто как ещё один выход из проблемы можно попробовать данный вариант (но про опечатку понял)